# how to debug my program when compiler gave no error

Tags: c++

i am coding a program which prints out perfect number in a given range, i did complete the code with no error but the program gives nothing in the output. I am using Visual Studio with very little experiment. Could some one point out what i did wrong or suggest a compiler which can help me tracking my program's process, so i can see which line i did wrong. Thank you!

```
void main()
{
int n,i,j,sum=0;
printf("input the value n: \n");
scanf_s("%d", &n);
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
        for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (i%j == 0)
            {
             sum = sum + j;
            }
        }
        if (sum == i)
        {
            printf("%d", i);
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger - gdb, Visual Studio for example

Comment: Does the program give no output at all?

Comment: you can use Visual studio debugger

Comment: @Jay yes, it lets me input the n value then jump straight to "press any key to continue ", nothing happened

Comment: I think you need to reset `sum` to 0 at the beginning of each outer loop iteration.

Comment: Learning to use a debugger will serve you well in the future.  The alternative is to add print statement to your code to see what's going on inside.  For example, adding `printf("i: %d, j: %d, sum: %d\n", i, j, sum);` just before the closing `}` of the inner `for` loop might let you see what's going wrong.

Comment: Add a `fflush(stdout);` after printing. See if it helps.

Comment: @Khoa.Huynh If you want to debug this program, you need to set "breakpoints". Since the program executes top to bottom, set a first breakpoint at the first line (e.g., "int i...", for example. On VS, click on the first line, and then right-click to see the menu. Choose "set a breakpoint" or something like that. Then, run the program via "debug" (F5). Once the program starts, it'll stop at this breakpoint. Then you can continue, step one statement, etc. See the options on the debug menu toolbar. It'll take a bit of practice if you are new to debugging. But, it'll be your worthwhile.

Comment: @VTT thank you, this helped, i got it now

Comment: @realharry thank you mate, now i can see how the variables "sum" changed its value. This helped alots